tbl_merge changes order of variables?
I have a question regarding modifying the order of labels in tbl_regression and tbl_merge.
This is the code and output for:
gtsummary::tbl_regression(model2,               
                              tidy_fun = purrr::partial(tidy_robust, vcov = "HC1"),
                              label = list(national_centre ~ "National centre",year~ "Year")) %>% 
  add_significance_stars() %>% 
add_glance_table(   label = list(sigma ~ "\U03C3"),                                                    include = c(r.squared, AIC, sigma))





Characteristic
Beta
SE




Treat
-3.3
8.94


Year




2022
—
—


2023
-2.4
14.5


National centre
-17
9.22


Treat             * Year




Treat             * 2023
35*
14.5


R²
0.331



AIC
113



σ
21.0




However, when I merge regression summaries, the row "National centre" goes after the glance table. See code and output:
t5<-gtsummary::tbl_regression(model5,
                              tidy_fun = purrr::partial(tidy_robust, vcov = "HC1"),
                              label = list(year~ "Year")
) %>% add_significance_stars() %>% add_glance_table(   label = list(sigma ~ "\U03C3"),
                                                       include = c(r.squared, AIC, sigma))

t2<-gtsummary::tbl_regression(model2,                   
                              tidy_fun = purrr::partial(tidy_robust, vcov = "HC1"),
                              label = list(national_centre ~ "National centre",year~ "Year"))%>% 
  add_significance_stars() %>% add_glance_table(   label = list(sigma ~ "\U03C3"),
                                                    include = c(r.squared, AIC, sigma))

gtsummary::tbl_merge(list(t5,t2),    tab_spanner = c("**a**",
                                                           "**b**")




Characteristic
Beta
SE
Beta
SE




Treat
-2.1
9.84
-3.3
8.94


Year






2022
—
—
—
—


2023
-6.3
8.49
-2.4
14.5


Treat * Year






Treat * 2023
39*
16.2
35*
14.5


R²
0.341

0.331



AIC
174

113



σ
16.4

21.0



National centre


-17
9.22




The add_glance_table() help file has a tip explaining how to get what you are after. https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/add_glance.html#tips-1
